# Percentile calculation: Can I convert this for loop to a vector operation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of scores as input and I would like to output an array with the percentile attached to each score. And i am consciously not using `stats.percentileofscore()` as I am using this as an opportunity to learn numpy data handling and manipulation.

Given the input:

```py
math_scores = np.array([51, 61, 45, 72, 78, 61, 84, 50, 42, 57])
```

I expect the output of `print(scores_with_percentile)` to be:

```
[[51 35]
 [61 60]
 [45 15]
 [72 75]
 [78 85]
 [61 60]
 [84 95]
 [50 25]
 [42  5]
 [57 45]]
```

The calculation is based on the formula from this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile_rank)

I wrote the following code:

```py
math_scores = np.array([51, 61, 45, 72, 78, 61, 84, 50, 42, 57])
data_size = math_scores.shape
percentile_col = np.zeros(data_size, dtype=int)

for i, score in enumerate(math_scores):
    count = (math_scores < score).sum()
    freq = (math_scores == score).sum()
    percentile_col[i] = (count + (0.5*freq))*100/data_size

scores_with_percentile = np.stack((math_scores, percentile_col), axis=1)
print(scores_with_percentile)
```

which works fine for me though am sure it not be very efficient, as am only starting to become familiar with numpy.
I want to know if I can avoid the for loop by using some vector operations instead.
Any other suggestions to improve the code are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever, we want to loop over the elements of the same numpy array , we can create another array in the new axis.So we can use the vectorized functions of numpy on the 2D array.

```
math_scores = np.array([51, 61, 45, 72, 78, 61, 84, 50, 42, 57])
data_size = math_scores.shape
count = np.less(math_scores, math_scores[:,np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)
freq = np.equal(math_scores,math_scores[:,np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)
percentile_col = (count + (0.5*freq))*100/data_size

scores_with_percentile = np.stack((math_scores, percentile_col), axis=1)
print(scores_with_percentile)

[[51. 35.]
 [61. 60.]
 [45. 15.]
 [72. 75.]
 [78. 85.]
 [61. 60.]
 [84. 95.]
 [50. 25.]
 [42.  5.]
 [57. 45.]]
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I didnt know about np.less and np.equal.
I used the < and == directly and I suppose it should be equivalent:
`count = (math_scores < math_scores[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1);
freq = (math_scores == math_scores[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to count how many items are smaller than or equal to specicific item each multiple times while you are looping through array. It costs a lot of time, actually O(n) for any element and O(n²) for all of them. It would be a nice to have a sorted version of your scores, then it would cost O(log(n)) time for any element and O(nlog(n)) for all of them. This is what `numpy`'s `searchsorted` method was designed for. Of course, you need to sort your scores at first (this is also O(nlog(n))). This is what I have tried so far:

```
sorted_math_scores = np.sort(math_scores)
count = np.searchsorted(sorted_math_scores, math_scores)
freq = np.searchsorted(sorted_math_scores, math_scores, side='right') - count
percentile_col = (count + (0.5*freq))*100/data_size
```

Btw, I've put a lot of efforts to find a more specific way to find `freq` but with no fortune.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly defining a function for the percentile calculation and then mapping it over your array might be the best option here:

```py
math_scores = np.array([51, 61, 45, 72, 78, 61, 84, 50, 42, 57])

def compute_percentile(scores, score):
    count = (scores < score).sum()
    freq = (scores == score).sum()
    return (count + (0.5*freq))*100/len(scores)

output = np.array([(math_score, compute_percentile(math_scores, math_score)) for math_score in math_scores])
```

I attempted to replicate the behaviour using `np.vectorize` and some other fancy numpy functions, but either I couldn't get it to work, or the solution was extremely bloated.

Comment: It's not the best. Python - based 'for' loops are slow and numpy  is designed over C - based 'for loops. I've seen one example it's even 70 times slower.